# How to map an infinite iterator class instance to a parallel processing Pool for web requests

Tags: python, json, python-requests, multiprocessing

I'm trying to design a program which will make requests to a website's front-end api until it no-longer yields results. This is because the api serves up json data as a list of n dicts where n is the number of results per page and the total number of pages is unknown.

```
api_result = [{"name":"name1", "feature":"feature1"}, {"name":"name2", 
"feature":"feature2"}]
```

The way I have set up the code is through three separate modules; 1) the executable module which imports the other two and outlines the multiprocessing execution, 2) the actual request logic which both sends the requests and checks to see if they are still yielding results and 3) a custom iterator class which ultimately is passed to the `Pool().imap_unordered()` function as the iterable.

This is the iterator:

```py
class UrlIter(object):

    def __init__(self, per_page=100):
        self.per_page = per_page

    def __iter__(self):
        self.offset = 0
        self.url = "https://<some_website>.com/v1/<some_querystring_parameters>&limit={}&offset={}".format(self.per_page, self.offset)
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        url = self.url
        self.offset += self.per_page
        self.url = "https://<some_website>.com/v1/<some_querystring_parameters>&limit={}&offset={}".format(self.per_page, self.offset)
        return url
```

This is the request logic:

```py
class ExecuteRequests(object):

    def __init__(self, parser, per_page):
        self.parser = parser
        self.per_page = per_page
        self.offset = 0
        self.payload = {"<params>":"<some_params>", "url":None}
        self.run = True

    def execute(self, url):
        if self.run:
            self.payload["url"] = url

            r = requests.get(url, params = self.payload)

            data = self.parser.get_data(r.json())

            if len(data) < self.per_page: 
                self.run = False

        return data
```

Finally, this is the executable logic:

```py
def clean_data(data):

    clean_data = {}

    <some cleaning on 'data'>

    clean_data["n_items"] = n_items
    clean_data["item_list"] = item_list

    return clean_data


def main():
    data = []
    parser = parser_module.Parser()
    executor = executable_module.ExecuteRequests(parser = parser, per_page = 100)
    url_iterator = iter(iterator_module.UrlIter())

    p = Pool(15)

    for x in p.imap_unordered(executor.execute, url_iterator, 1):
        data.append(x)
    data = clean_data(data)

    return data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = main()
```

What I expected to receive from this, is a dict() object with two keys; "n_items" and "item_list". Instead, when I run this program, I get the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 121, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "C:\Users\<user>\<path>\executable_module.py", line 26, in execute
    jdata = r.json()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 897, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "project_93749.py", line 52, in <module>
    data = main()
  File "project_93749.py", line 41, in main
    for x in p.imap_unordered(executor.execute, url_iterator, 10):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 354, in <genexpr>
    return (item for chunk in result for item in chunk)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 748, in next
    raise value
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I have tried to use `urllib.request Request()` to see if this was a json handling issue but this resulted in the same error. I have also tested the core logic outside of this build - i.e. just sending a request to a few of the urls that come out of the iterator with the same payloads and these all work perfectly and as expected which confuses me as I read the error message above as "the data you asked to be in json format is not in json format" but the response headers note;

```
{"content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8", "content-encoding":"gzip"}
```

Therefore, I suspect that I have not implemented the `Pool().imap_unordered()` correctly. Thank you.

Comment: Apparently the web site sends a different response when you connect to it from 15 simultaneous threads. Being nice and keeping the resource usage to a minimum is a good idea while scraping web sites.

Comment: @Selcuk all requests are coming from a pool of paid VPNs so while I do completely agree with your comment, this shouldn't have impacted the performance as each request would have come from a different VPN / user-agent.